# Game Services classes Cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-play-games

I want to implement Google Play Game Services. But in GameHelper class the following classes could not be found at compilation.

import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;

import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager;

import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Multiplayer;

import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

Error:

The import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager cannot be resolved   GameHelper.java

I already read the google docs about Game Services and made all like that. In App Billings works great. So I have integrated the library project of Google Play Services in the right way.

Does anyone know something about this problem?

Comment: Have you added the library to your project?

Comment: yes I have added a reference to the library project of google play services. and the android support v4 library (.jar file) added too

Comment: And all other classes for example this one: import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes; works

Comment: Have you added reference to google_play_services_lib that can be downloaded from the SDK Manager?

Comment: Yes, I have added the reference to google play services lib from SDK Manager, thx

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in Helper class like below

```
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Multiplayer;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
```

My solution was updating google play services. Now I dont get any error

Comment: Just saying 'updating Google Play servers' needs to be explained further I think.  I've noticed that the SDK Manager sometimes refuses to update some of the 'Extras' - on my laptop it's stuck at Version 13 (which would cause this error - current version is 18!)

My solution was to steal the .jar file from my desktop - I've since removed and completely re-installed the SDK on the laptop and it STILL won't get past 13 tho - so be wily!!

Answer (score 0):

In the git repository look for classes in: `EndlessTunnel\BaseGameUtils\src\com\google\example\games\basegameutils\`

This may not be the perfect solution, but the git repository contains 3 directories containing the `GameHelper.java` (and in the same folder, its related `BaseGameActivity.java`).

After many hours I've finally managed to get rid of all the errors, but I have yet to test if this will cause any limitations.